# Either quiet or quietly

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

In the following sentence is **quietly** incorrectly used?

> I was surprised to see every student sitting quietly in the class, even though the teacher was not present

According to my book **quietly** is wrong and in its place **quiet** should be used. But I think quietly is also correct since it modifies the verb **sitting**.

Comment: Indeed, 'quietly' is an adverb and correct in this instance.

Comment: The following is also correct, but only because of the punctuation that allows an adjective in a nonrestrictive (parenthetical) aside: *I was surprised to see every student sitting, quiet, in the class …*